# Make Jenkins create unique workdir for concurrent build in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, concurrency

Originally, Jenkins was creating a unique workdir if concurrency was enabled for the job. With Kubernetes plugin, I can see Jenkins uses same workdir (project name), even for concurrent builds (they are enabled by default now). I tried passing `$JENKINS_AGENT_NAME` variable into workdir settings of Kubernetes plugin, but it didn't work, the variable is not being expanded, I just get literally `$JENKINS_AGENT_NAME` in workdir path.
Is there any way to make Jenkins create unique workdirs for concurrent builds with declarative pipeline and agents in Kubernetes?